# Trying to cythonize a class with an attribute (ctypes.c_float * 60)

Tags: python, arrays, opengl-es-2.0, cython, ctypes

I am trying to cythonize some of the pi3d module (which has been working ok for several years). The Shape class contains a uniform variable array that is passed to an OpenGL ES 2.0 function with spec:
`void glUniform3fv(GLint location, GLsizei count, const GLfloat *value)` in the pure python version the variable is defined in `Shape.__init__()`

```
self.unif = (ctypes.c_float * 60) (x, y, z, rx, ry, rz...
#... then later passed as an argument to a function as unif and used like
opengles.glUniform3fv(shader.unif_unif, 20, ctypes.byref(unif))
```

I was hoping to leave the py file unaltered and add cython specifications in a pxd file like this

```
cdef class Shape(Loadable):
  cdef:
    public float[60] unif
    public object shader
    public list textures, buf, children
    ...
```

which compiles ok but unif has become a `list` instead of a `c_float_Array_60` object which it is in the pure python and the ctypes.byref(unif) fails.

If I make unif into a numpy array then it will compile and I can get some (incorrect) rendering using the horrible

```
opengles.glUniform3fv(shader.unif_unif, 20, ctypes.byref(
                  unif.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)))
                     )
```

So my question is: how should I specify the fact that the unif attribute is a `c_float_Array_60` object in the pxd file. Or is this not possible?

Comment: The pointer from `data_as` shouldn't be passed `byref`. That's passing the address of the pointer instead of the address of the first element. Also, in your first example with a ctypes array, passing it `byref` is redundant. A C array is naturally passed as a pointer to the first element.

Comment: If the 3rd parameter of `glUniform3fv.argtypes` is set to `c_void_p`, then you can use `unif.ctypes` instead of a `data_as` cast, which works because `unif.ctypes._as_parameter_` is a `c_void_p` instance. Or if the parameter is set to `np.ctypeslib.ndpointer('f', 1)` in `argtypes`, you can pass `unif` directly.

Comment: @eryksun, excellent advice! I have stripped out quite a few byref function call throughout the module. I had already set the third argtype to c_void_p but using your np.ctypeslib.ndpointer suggestion is really nice. I had to specifically set the dtype=np.float32 but, on this machine at least, the full test set run fine. Thanks again. (I think it was the float32 issue that made it half work previously (and induced me to take the address of a pointer!))

Comment: Sadly the switch to numpy arrays from ctypes seems to have a fairly drastic impact on speed. Also the cython compiling doesn't make much difference, so I will revert the changes for the time being.